# Converting Seq[T] into Option[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, seq

Scala Seq includes methods that are illegal or undefined for an empty sequence, e.g max

To protect myself from this I often address the problem by wrapping the sequence in an option and mapping empty to None. It can be done like this:

```
def wrap[T](s: Seq[T]): Option[Seq[T]] =
    s.headOption map { _ => s }
```

It could also be solved by pattern matching or if-else.

None of the approaches are easy to use in a fluent way, and frankly seem a bit awkward.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
someStore
   .giveMeASequence
   .wrapInOption map { nonEmpty:Seq[T] =>
      nonEmpty.max
    } map (_ + 42)
```

I'm hesitant to wrap the operation in the Try monad because the exception can be predicted and avoided.

Am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

If not, are there any library methods available to me to make it less awkward?

Comment: You could look into using scalaz's `NonEmptyList`

Comment: @cmbaxter Thank you. My problem is that I can't guarantee that the sequence is non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the scalaz `NonEmptyList` class could be helpful to you.  By importing the scalaz pimping, you get access to the `toNel` method that you can call on a `List`.  If this list is indeed empty, you can not continue to map over it.  If it's not empty, you can indeed map over it.  Consider the following example:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val nonEmpty = List(1,2,3)
val result = 
  nonEmpty.
    toNel.
    map(_.list.max).
    map(_ + 42)

println(result)
```

If you run this code, it will print `Some(45)`.  Had that list been empty, it would result in a `None`.

Comment: If you're not already using scalaz, I don't think it makes sense to add it in order to use a one line method.

Comment: @KimStebel, I agree mostly, but if you are already using it it's a good solution, and if you aren't, it might be a gateway into using it more in your codebase.  It's a good library for solving a lot of common problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to do the conversion, why not use if/else?

```
def wrap[A](s: Seq[A]) = if (s.isEmpty) None else Some(s)
```

Alternatively, you can define your own `maxOpt` method:

```
implicit def seqWithMaxOpt[A:Ordering](s:Seq[A]) =
  new { def maxOpt = Try(s.max).toOption }
```

And call it like so

```
val s:Seq[Int] = Seq()
s.maxOpt
```

In the same manner, you could add a method that wraps a sequence in an Option:

```
   implicit def seqWithOptionWrapping[A](s:Seq[A]) =
  new { def wrapInOption = if (s.isEmpty) None else Some(s) }
```

Comment: Apart from the ```Try(s.max).toOption``` this solution is quite agreeable to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `Seq` with your safe methods via implicit class:

```
 implicit class SafeSeq[T](s: Seq[T]) {
    def safeMax(implicit cmp: Ordering[T]): Option[T] =
      if (s.isEmpty) None
      else Some(s.max)

    //other safe operations you want
  }

  println(Seq.empty[Int].safeMax.map(_ + 42)) // None
  println(Seq(1).safeMax.map(_ + 42))         // Some(43)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure this is less awkward, but it's solution I would probably use if I had to use max multiple times.

Comment: it's a common way to enrich class functionality in scala